# How to use Supervisor + Django + Celery with multiple Queues and Workers?

Tags: celery, django-celery, supervisord

I'm using Celery + Django + Supervisord and I'm trying to setup a "priority" by creating 3 different queues (as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15827160/54872).

Is there a way to start celery beat and workers for each queue in one command for supervisor? Or, do I need to make different supervisor conf files for each queue/worker pool and one for celery beat?

Answer (score 24):

You can create [program](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings) sections for each queue and combine them in a [group](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#group-x-section-settings) section:

```
[program:worker1]
command=celery worker --queues=queue1

[program:worker2]
command=celery worker --queues=queue2

[group:workers]
programs=worker1,worker2
```